# Ember value bindings aren't working in view objects

Tags: data-binding, ember.js, view

So I've been running into this issue where I can't seem to get values from my templates to my view objects.

For instance, take this signin form:

```
App.AuthSignInView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'auth/sign_in'

  email:    null
  password: null

  submit: (event, view) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    App.Auth.signIn
      data:
        email:    @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
```

And this template:

```
<form>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="email"}}
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="password"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-inverse">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

When the view attempts to access the email and password properties on submit, they are still null. I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong here, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: just edited my example to include the submit so you can test the binding better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not a good practice to have your view's holding state for your app, everything logic related should be done in controllers, which is the default lookup place for values defined in your templates. But if you really need your values to be on your view you should prefix you value bindings with `view.email` and `view.password` in your templates to have it use the values on your view.

See here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivegur/3/edit) using the `view` approach.

And here an example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivegur/7/edit) using the `controller` which is the recommended way.

Hope it helps.